# Raid 0+1 on only 2 disks

Tags: hard-drive, raid

Is it possible to configure 2 disk to have the redundancy of Raid 1 and the speed of Raid 0 ?
In a way like this:

```
Disk 1          Disk2
----------------------
Data 1          Data 2   --> Raid 0

Data 1          Data 1   --> Raid 1
Data 2          Data 2
```

This way, all data is rapidly accessible, from the Raid 0 part, and all disk contains a copy of the all data, so if one of the disk fails, it is possible to recover all data.

I know it would not be optimal for space (with two 1 To disks, only 500 Go would be usable, so 25%), but I ask if it possible to configure. (I searched for hours, but found nothing with this kind of idea, and this makes me very curious)

Comment: IO overhead would eat any and all advantages this may appear to give. Controller overhead would make it slower than direct disk access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, technically it is possible.

But you do **not** gain the speed of RAID0. I expect it to be significantly slower than even using a single disk. Which is probably the reason why you do not find it on-line.

The main advantage of RAID 0 is that it can use two drives at the same time. That allows for double troughput. But if you use multiple partitions on the same drive then a classical HDD needs to move its head a lot. And that will cause a **significant** slowdown.

Comment: Even on a SSD? Since they are quite rapid with random writes

Comment: SSDs do not suffer that disadvantage, (hence my reference to spinning rust... ehm, classical HDDs), but neither do you gain much here. Mirrors (RAID1) are used for reliability, stripes (RAID0) for speed. Tryng to combine those is heaving the cake and eating it. If people do not do that (and believe me, people are greedy) then there usually is a good reason for it.